# Pandas: Treating HTML as a Float...?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to count the number of images in a bunch of HTML files that I've read into a Pandas DataFrame (under the `_text` column).  My attempt is here:

```
text_img_count = [len(BeautifulSoup(x, "lxml").find_all('img')) for x in df['_text']]
```

However, I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-1d0e442bf1d1> in <module>()
----> 1 text_img_count = [len(BeautifulSoup(x, "lxml").find_all('img')) for x in df['_text']]
      2 text_vid_count = [len(BeautifulSoup(x, "lxml").find_all('video')) for x in df['_text']]
      3 text_link_count = [len(BeautifulSoup(x, "lxml").find_all('a')) for x in result_df['_text']]
      4 df['_text_img_count'] = text_img_count
      5 df['_text_vid_count'] = text_vid_count

/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/__init__.pyc in __init__(self, markup, features, builder, parse_only, from_encoding, exclude_encodings, **kwargs)
    190         if hasattr(markup, 'read'):        # It's a file-type object.
    191             markup = markup.read()
--> 192         elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
    193                 (isinstance(markup, bytes) and not b'<' in markup)
    194                 or (isinstance(markup, unicode) and not u'<' in markup)

TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

So then I check the type of my `_text` column and it's a float...

I used `df = pd.read_csv('full_data.csv', index_col=0)` to read my data in.  I'm a little confused by why it read my HTML markup in as a float...

Any idea how to fix?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more information about the contents of full_data.csv. You claim it's a "bunch of html files", but then why is it a csv? It sounds like it has a _text column with float values.

Comment: @Personman full_data.csv has a column that contains HTML markup, that's why I'm unsure why it's read into the dataframe as a float.  I've inspected the data with `df.head()` and it appears fine.  Does that clarify?